# On pushing object in array the vue ui is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuex, vuejs3

I am stucked in a problem where I have created a custom drag drop component which is working fine,

there is an array which is connected to vuex store, i have created the mutations to update or add new object inside the array that array is getting changed after drop operation but the ui is not getting changed

I am fetching that array using `this.$store.getters['moduleName/functionName']`

**mutation.js**=>

```
   export default {
       setNewValue(state, payload){
           state.arr.push(payload);
       }
   }
```

**handleDrop function** =>

```
handleDrop(event, data){
     let actionType = this.$store.getters["moduleName/getActionType"];
     let obj;
     let length = this.$store.getters["moduleName/getLengthOfArr"];
        obj = {
          id: length == 0 ? 1 : length + 1,
          name: data.name,
          isConditional: false,
          ...actionType[data.type],
          yes: [],
          no: [],
        };
        this.$store.commit("moduleName/setNewValue", obj);
```

action Type are some objects which i need to add based on data type provided

i guess it is due to reactivity of object properties or due to computed property which i am using in ui

```
computed : {
     arr(){
         return this.$store.getters['moduleName/getArray'];
     }
}
```

***getters.js***

```
export default {
    getArray(state){
         return state.arr;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that `state.arr` is not an array - but an object. When you drop the dragged element - you should remove it from the original array (with the help of `Array.splice`) and then add it to the new array (with `Array.push`)

Comment: actually the arr holds complex nested objects and i guess it is truly a reactive issue and computed property is not getting updated as it has been cached, you said is correct can you please help me out and demostrate with example if arr is empty and if it is filled ? Thanks in advance @IVOGELOV

Comment: It does not matter how complex are the objects **inside** `state.arr` - what matters is that you are assigning another **object** to it but instead it needs to be an **array** of complex nested objects. Dragging and dropping means that you move an **item** from one **array** of items to another **array** of items. Notice the distinction - dragging works with arrays, not objects. The item that you are dragging is probably an object - but you do not modify the item itself, you modify the source and destination **arrays**.

Comment: Bro i am getting the dragged object inside the proxy array but in ui the first dragged object is getting cached and rest if i drag the same thing is repeated i.e. cached object is seen in ui but in store we get correct array

Comment: how can we push a proxied array a new object i am doing some research in google but no answers i can get please help

Comment: sorry i made a mistake while writing the question, i got what you were telling, but the problem still persist

Comment: Regrettably, the answer is still the same. Try Googling a little more ...

Comment: The thing is vue 3 is very new and not much are being answered or known to it 
i have put it in forum.vuejs.org as well no help its related to computed property being cached and not re rendering the dom but data is getting updated in vuex store,

hence its vuejs reactivity issue.

Comment: If you are sure it is a bug in Vue 3 - you should file an issue on Github. If your code works in Vue 2 - then you can demonstrate to the maintainers that the bug is in Vue code and not in yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some debugging i solved the problem as the problem was with rendering the data was getting updated and even store was getting updated

while rendering i was using the same object which was rendered previously but that made me so much confused due to vuejs' reactivity with computed property.